# Create and cast a new column from existing column with % concatenation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe

```text
Month       Location    Sales
1/1/2020    India       0.4799
1/1/2020    USA         0.08840739
2/1/2020    Australia   0.1957
2/1/2020    China       0.204
```

I need to create a new column `Sales_new` with `%` concatenated and retain only 2 digits after the decimal point from `Sales` column
So my desired dataframe will be

```text
Month       Location    Sales_new
1/1/2020    India       47.99%
1/1/2020    USA         8.84%
2/1/2020    Australia   19.57%
2/1/2020    China       20.4%
```

I tried with this code:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('Sales_new', F.round(F.concat(col('Sales')*100, F.lit("%")),1))
```

and I'm getting:

```text
Month       Location    Sales_new
1/1/2020    India       null
1/1/2020    USA         null
2/1/2020    Australia   null
2/1/2020    China       null
```

Am I missing something? Any other approaches, please suggest

Answer (score 4):

You should execute `round` first, and then execute `concat`.

```
df1 = df.withColumn('Sales_new', F.concat(F.round(F.col('Sales')*100, 2), F.lit("%")))
df1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format_number` instead of rounding and concatenating:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn('Sales_new', F.expr("format_number(Sales, '0.##%')"))

df1.show()
#+--------+---------+----------+---------+
#|   Month| Location|     Sales|Sales_new|
#+--------+---------+----------+---------+
#|1/1/2020|    India|    0.4799|   47.99%|
#|1/1/2020|      USA|0.08840739|    8.84%|
#|2/1/2020|Australia|    0.1957|   19.57%|
#|2/1/2020|    China|     0.204|    20.4%|
#+--------+---------+----------+---------+
```